# How to make my java app run when run specific extension?

Tags: java

I want to make my program start when certain file extensions are opened. For example, when you click on a `.zip` file in Windows, Winzip starts up.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: I understand you may not be English, but you should spend a little more time on your spelling and grammar to elicit more answers.

Comment: I think this should go on the SuperUser site.

Answer (score 3):

That is called a 'File Type association'. Here is how you create and edit them in Win7/Vista: http://www.winvistaclub.com/t19.html

in your case, you would create a file type extension for your custom file type, and then create an association to open files of that type with your java application.